# Why do I get a ValueError when using datetime.max?

Tags: python, python-datetime, python-3.8

Why do I get a `ValueError` in this example?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.max.timestamp()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: year 10000 is out of range
```

I'm using Python 3.8.3.

Comment: One thing to note that the system timezone hosting that Python instance is ahead of UTC, such that when an internal conversion hits, the year is pushed over 9999 (due to local time being ahead) thus causing that error.

Comment: I wonder what you want to use that value for...

Comment: See CPython [src](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_datetimemodule.c): maximum value for year is 9999. Regardless if this is useful or not, why is a year > 9999 an issue? is that maybe a matter of floating point precision of the resulting timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timestamp()` method actually converts your datetime in **local** timezone. If your timezone is **UTC**+x (not **UTC**-x); i.e. your timezone is ahead of UTC time; Then it will add more time in your datetime object (`datetime.datetime.max`) which will cross the time beyond the year **9999**. That is why your code gives that error.

Below is an example to validate it:

```
val1 = datetime.datetime.now()  # datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 15, 15, 54, 15, 214349)
```

`val1` is the exact time in my timezone, but there is no timezone associated with it (so it will take **local** timezone as `datetime.datetime.max` would take). You can check the timezone in datetime object using `val1.tzinfo`. If it returns blank, that means code assumes the time is in **local** timezone.

I have created one more object with same time but in UTC timezone:

```
val2 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2020-06-15T15:54:15.214349+00:00")
```

I print the values:

```
print(val1.timestamp()) # 1592216655.214349
print(val2.timestamp()) # 1592236455.214349
```

If you calculate the difference between the two values, it will give 19,800 seconds (which is 5.5 hours), which is exactly my timezone (IST or you can say UTC+5:30) difference from UTC.

Answer (score 1):

I get an `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` using Python 3.6. This is what the documentation says:

**Note**

There is no method to obtain the POSIX timestamp directly from a naive datetime instance representing UTC time. If your application uses this convention and your system timezone is not set to UTC, you can obtain the POSIX timestamp by supplying tzinfo=timezone.utc:

```
timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
```

or by calculating the timestamp directly:

```
timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)
```

So when I tried:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.max.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
253402300800.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason is datetime.timestamp() returns POSIX timestamp that overflows in 2038, and datetime.max is in year 9999.

Search online for "Year 2038 problem" for more information.

Answer (score -1):

your syntax is incorrect ..
`datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None, *, fold=0)`
The year, month and day arguments are required. tzinfo may be None, or an instance of a tzinfo subclass. The remaining arguments must be integers in the following ranges:

MINYEAR <= year <= MAXYEAR,

1 <= month <= 12,

1 <= day <= number of days in the given month and year,

0 <= hour < 24,

0 <= minute < 60,

0 <= second < 60,

0 <= microsecond < 1000000,

fold in [0, 1].

Comment: please don't accuse people of using syntax incorrectly without explanation. don't just quote the docs, add an explanation *what* is incorrect.